# riot js pushing index to a array

Tags: javascript, riot.js

I woking in riot js and i have sorted the following `abclist` as following.

```
abclist = [];
abc = {year:year, name1:name1, order:order};
abclist.push(abc);

abclist.sort(function(a,b) {return (a.order > b.order) ? 1 : ((b.order > a.order) ? -1 : 0);} );
```

printing on console the `abclist` is like below.

```
0: {year: "2018", name1: "cc", order: "1"}
1: {year: "2018", name1: "jj", order: "2"}
```

I want to add these array index(0,1)to the array like below.

```
0: {index:0, year: "2018", name1: "cc", order: "1"}
1: {index:1, year: "2018", name1: "jj", order: "2"}
```

Please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

The question is not strictly related to riot.

An easy way to achieve that is to reiterate the array and add a field to each object like this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < abclist.length; i++){
    abclist[i]['index'] = i; 
}
```

You can see it in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7esmssup/6/